# Shadow text with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I been working all day to add shadow to text using command line imagemagick. Googled many pages and experimented with gaussian, blur, shadow commands for dropping shadow but no success.

Here is my command in php:

```
$img_save = 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\testimage.jpg';

$line = "Anatidaephobia is the fear that somewhere in the world there is a duck watching you. ";
$line = wordwrap($line, 25, "\\n");   

exec("convert -background white -weight bold -size 500x -pointsize 35 -font arial-italic -gravity center -fill black caption:\"$line\" $img_save");
```

The above code gives image without difficulty. Can anyone tell how to add shadow to text in the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to draw the shadow first then draw over it with the font

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:white -pointsize 35 -font arial-italic -gravity center       - fill red -draw "text 2,2 'text'" -fill black -draw "text 0,0 'text'" outfile.jpg
```

Comment: I can't word wrap with this.

Answer (score 1):

With `caption` just `clone` and shadow it with,

```
convert logo: -resize 40%x40 \
    \( -size "80x40" -background none -gravity west \
    -fill green caption:"Caption text" \
    \( +clone -background navy -shadow 80x3+5+5  \) \
    +swap -background none -layers merge +repage \)  -composite out.png
```

[image]